# remove_binary Option ElasticsearchClient

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-client

The official docs for Elasticsearch state that there is a `remove_binary` option you can define when setting up an attachment ingestion pipeline: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/attachment.html

I am using the official C# client and ES8:

```
// client creation/connection removed

// Define the ingest pipeline
var ingestPipelineResult = await client.Ingest.PutPipelineAsync("attachment", p => 
    p.Processors(x =>
    {
        x.Attachment<Document>(a =>
        {
            a.Field(f => f.Data);
            a.IndexedChars(-1);
            a.RemoveBinary(true); // this is what I want; not a real thing
        });
    }));
```

And for the sake of completeness, the Document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; } //Base64 encoded
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, the `RemoveBinary` method isn't real, so my question is whether it's possible to set this via the ElasticsearchClient. If so, how? A couple of (clunky) work arounds exist: a) I can re-put the document after removing the `data` property, b) I can create an authenticated `HttpClient` and post directly against the API. Neither of these are desirable, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the RemoveBinary method isn't real"? This method does not work for you? Might be a silly question as I don't know C# ;). But I wrote this feature in the ingest attachment processor...

Comment: It doesn't exist in the C# ElasticsearchClient. It's want I want to be able to do, so I threw it on there for illustration. I feel like there has to be a work-around to set `remove_binary` to true somehow, but it's escaping me!

Comment: I guess the workaround would be to use the low level part of the client if it exists (like in Java). But I guess you should open an issue to fix this missing piece... Is it not possible to send a JSON document to this PutPipelineAsync thing?